# What is the difference between clothing and clothes?

Tags: differences

There is a story that 
a worker at the airport, while unloading a number of boxes, 
accidentally discovered a man who was hiding in a box in order to save the cost of the trip. 
The man was lying on the top of a pile of WOOLEN GOODS.

And my question is if I intend to replace WOOLEN GOODS with some other type of goods,
for example, CLOTHES or CLOTHING, which one is better? 
And what is the difference on this occasion? 
Please explain in detail, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When we speak of *clothes* we normally have in mind garments as worn by ourselves and other individuals. *Clothing* describe garments in general without reference to their being worn by anyone in particular.